# Is there a way for a time input to be strictly 24-hour format?

Tags: javascript, html, input, time

I'm creating a form that asks the user for a time, and I want that input field to be strictly in 24-hour format.

I've read, at the following link, that time inputs will be different depending on if the user has their time in a 12 or 24-hour format.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Appearance

I've tried reading through moment.js but wasn't sure any of that information would be helpful with achieving what I'm setting out to do.

The basic code I'm using is this:

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="frequencyInput">
```

I am using HTML with bootstrap

My goal is to have the input be in a 24-hour format regardless of browser. I prefer to stick with HTML, javascript, and jquery but will be open to trying any and all suggestions.

Comment: Given that it'll `POST` as a consistent format, and be accessible to JS in a consistent format, why care? "The value of the time input is always in 24-hour format that includes leading zeros: hh:mm, regardless of the input format, which is likely to be selected based on the user's locale (or by the user agent)."

Comment: @ceejayoz—because in some cases, 24 hour format is preferable to 12 hr + am/pm, e.g. airline schedules (13:15 is also shorter and more easily compared to other times than 1:15 pm). Clarity and unambiguity should trump local preferences. ;-)

Comment: (Forcing) 24-hour time formats are an option of some “decorated” (eg. non-native) inputs. These can also be the “most consistent” across browsers, even if introducing inconsistencies between different pages in the same browser.

Comment: if you need more control than the native `<input>` element, consider writing your own web component (try out lit-element!)